# What's the reason of my custom annotation of EnableRetrofitClients when use different order on this

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My English is poor so just look the code thanks

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented
@Import(RetrofitClientsRegistrar.class)
public @interface EnableRetrofitClients {}
```

this code is works good;

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(RetrofitClientsRegistrar.class)
```

this code is not work for me;

so why?

Comment: What makes you think it didn't work?

Comment: I run the spring boot application use first code my break-point will active and another will not active